# Xamarin Android app works on emulator, crashes on real device when using WebRequest

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-emulator, webrequest

I am using this example to get some data from a link to an Android device:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f(v=vs.110).aspx

The app works fine when using the emulator (Nexus 5 with Android Kit Kat), but when I deploy it (release version) on an actual Android (Samsung S3 mini with Jellybean) the app starts, but crashes after that with "Unfortunately .. has stopped working". If I don't use WebRequest.Create, all my other components in the app work everywhere.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
            "MY LINK HERE"); //with a real link ofcourse

        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();


        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd()

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for the http request?

Comment: I've added the code :)

Comment: Add a try catch clause and please provide the exception and also make sure your address isn't localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable Internet permission for App in AndroidManifest.xml file under Properties as follows:

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

or enable through wizard from following steps:

- Right click over project and Properties
- Under Android Manifest
- enable checkbox for **Internet** under Required Permissions
  [image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the ussue. I didn't know that I had to set permission to use internet.

Project->Project Options->Build->Android Application->Required permission-> Tick the Internet checkbox and press OK.

Comment: In Debug, Android will implicitly grant Internet permissions to your app.  In Release, you have to explicitly grant Internet permissions.